# ListRows.Add not copying all formulas to new row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with a subroutine to add a new row at the bottom.
When adding a new row, it will not copy the formula for 2 columns only.  All other formulas copy to the new line without issue.
I'm calling ListRows.Add
I've used this in several project without failure, but can't figure out why only 2 columns will not copy the formula to the new row.

Table details:
Name: tblFlights
Columns: 103
Protected Columns with formulas: A, P-S, U, AI-AM, AP-AW, AZ-BA, BG-BQ, BS-CB, CD-CG, CI-CO.
Un-protected Columns (for data entry): B-O, W-X, CY.

On the newly added row (at the bottom), Columns P & R formulas do not copy.
All other columns with formulas copy just fine.

I have also noticed that on Column P the "Protection" does not copy.  Column R "Protection" copies just fine.

These are the only 2 columns that have issues with ListRows.Add

When I manually do an Insert->Table Row Below, same issue happens.When I manually do an Insert->Table Row Above, same issue happens.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Chris

```
Sub btnInsertBottom()
Call SheetUnLock
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim NewRow As ListRow

Set Tbl = Range("tblFlights").ListObject
Set NewRow = Tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

Range("tblFlights[[#Headers],[Date (mm/dd/yy)]]").Select
Call btnGotoBottom

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call SheetLock
End Sub
```

Comment: There's something "off" about those two columns, but without seeing your sheet it's pretty difficult to know what that might be.

Comment: Try converting the table to a range and then back to a table - that might reset the problem columns

Comment: In each of the two columns (which currently do not populate new rows with the formula), check if the formula stays the same throughout the column. Sounds like something is preventing it from being a `calculated column`.

Comment: For each of the two columns, take a cell in that column which contains the correct formula, copy-paste it to the first cell of that column, then double-click the bottom right corner of the cell to overwrite the column (with what should be the same formula). Second thing you could try is recreating the columns themselves from scratch (if this is an option -- depending on how many cells refer to that column). Maybe just store the formulas somewhere temporarily, re-create the columns, run the VBA code you posted, check if the formulas were added to new rows (in the newly created columns)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, converting to range, then back didn't do the trick so I created another column as "chillin" suggested and changed the formulas that referenced the column and all is working as expected. Appreciated the responses